# How to findAll DTO from a repository

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a Repository from which I use two (herited) methods:

```
List<MyEntity> findAll(Specification<MyEntity> specification)
```

and the

```
Page<MyEntity> findAll(Specficiation<MyEntity> specification, Pageable page)
```

The repository looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, MyEntityId>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity> {
}
```

From this I wanted to change, to use DTOs instead of the entity (as it is a read only use case, so it would help with my performance issues).

So I went from

```
List<MyEntity> findAll(Specification<MyEntity> specification)
```

to

```
List<MyEntityDTO> findAll(Specification<MyEntity> specification)
```

Which of course is KO as it will override with the bad signature.
So I try to modify to:

```
List<MyEntityDTO> findAllProjectedBy(Specification<MyEntity> specification)
```

but then I got 0 parameter expected, and 1 given.
So my question is, how do I make a repository return a DTO instead of Entities if I want to make it happen the same way as findAll works.( the parametered versions).
Also tried findAllProjectedBySpecification / findAllProjectedByExample (it says no specification / example in the entity, well it is in fact true) and findProjectedAll (but syntax to allow the anything apart only before a "by")
I mean if findAll works as it is for the standard use case, I don't see why it does allow **Specification** and **Pageable** as parameter, if in a custom version of it I can not give one. (presuming findAll and findAllBy are semantically the same, but findAllProjected does not work neither...)

EDIT:
I ended up finding that there is an issue on this behavior :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1378
which explains why it is not working as seems logical.

Still looking for a way around this